# How do I get a docker container to automatically execute a bash script once it starts up?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-entrypoint

I'm stuck trying to achieve the objective described in the title. Tried various options last of which is found in [this](https://www.sentiatechblog.com/running-apache-in-a-docker-container) article. Currently my Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
EXPOSE 8081
CMD cd /var/www/html/components
CMD "bash myscript start" "-D" "FOREGROUND"
#ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "myscript", "start"]
```

Neither the CMD..."FOREGROUND" nor the commented-out ENTRYPOINT lines work. However, when I open an interactive shell into the container, cd into /var/.../components folder and execute the exact same command to run the script, it works.

What do I need to change?

Comment: make your bash script the entrypoint file

Comment: How exactly do I do that? How does it differ from the commented out ENTRYPOINT line?

Answer (score 0):

Once you pass your `.sh` file, run it with `CMD`. This is a snippet:

```
ADD ./configure.and.run.myapp.sh /tmp/
RUN chmod +x /tmp/configure.and.run.myapp.sh
...
CMD ["sh", "-c", "/tmp/configure.and.run.myapp.sh"]
```

And [here](https://github.com/fpezzati/jsci/blob/master/jsfcihelloworld/wildfly/Dockerfile.dev) is my full dockerfile, have a look.

Comment: So all I need do is CMD ["sh", "-c", "myscript start"] ?

Comment: When file is in place, `ADD ./configure.and.run.myapp.sh /yourcontainerworkdir` and you add execution permission, yes. Maybe it's better to update my answer..

Comment: You never need `CMD ["sh", "-c", ...]`.  If it's a simple command you can just run it using the JSON-array syntax `CMD ["the-script.sh"]`, or if you need the shell wrapper, use the Docker shell syntax `CMD the-script.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

I see three problems with the Dockerfile you've shown.

**There are multiple `CMD`s.**  A Docker container only runs one command (and then exits); if you have multiple `CMD` directives then only the last one has an effect.  If you want to change directories, use the `WORKDIR` directive instead.

**Nothing is `COPY`d into the image.**  Unless you explicitly `COPY` your script into the image, it won't be there when you go to run it.

**The `CMD` has too many quotes.**  In particular, the quotes around `"bash myscript start"` make it into a single shell word, and so the system looks for an executable program named exactly that, including spaces as part of the filename.

You should be able to correct this to something more like:

```bash
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# Instead of `CMD cd`; a short path like /app is very common
WORKDIR /var/www/html/components

# Make sure the application is part of the image
COPY ./ ./

EXPOSE 8081

# If the script is executable and begins with #!/bin/sh then
# you don't need to explicitly say "bash"; you probably do need
# the path if it's not in /usr/local/bin or similar
CMD ./myscript start -D FOREGROUND
```

(I tend to avoid `ENTRYPOINT` here, for two main reasons.  It's easier to `docker run --rm -it your-image bash` to get a debugging shell or run other one-off commands without an `ENTRYPOINT`, especially if the command requires arguments.  There's also a useful pattern of using `ENTRYPOINT` to do first-time setup before running the `CMD` and this is a little easier to set up if `CMD` is already the main container command.)

Comment: You’re right about not needing the bash as it worked directly from command line. Alas, these changes are not making the script execute at start up of the container. This is confusing to say the least!